# Hudge union calls aborted

Tags: mysql, performance, union

My problem is a big union combination that needs to return the same (complementary) fields, depending on different focuses.

The site is an ad service, based on carpooling : users can propose to take children to school or they can ask for their children to be taken.

7 tables  are involved :

- Besoin (which determine the need [proposal or request]],
- User,
- Annonce (contains specific ad informations fetched from 2 different
  tables (km_annoncesparents or km_annoncesaccompas) depending on the
  type of Besoin (proposal or request),
- Perimetre (indicates the proposal's area of action),
- Service (tells the time range of the proposal),
- LieuDepart (starting place),
- LieuArrivee (arrival place)

2 tables only are used commonly : Besoin and User. The others must be joined upon the Besoin type. And the whole result as to be sorted from the closest place matching the zip code of the User, to a dynamical range selected by the search call.

The following query worked well until we reached 2000 rows in the "Besoin" table. But it is a awfull monster that I can't stare at without fear! And, cherry on the cake, the server aborts this query now, with this message "<>: 1317 Query execution was interrupted". Certainly a time limit or something like this...

I'm not an SQL specialist and I would appreciate that somebody helps me, if possible, simplifying and optimizing this request. I didn't decide the database model. This was part of specifications that were given to me and changing that model is simply not feasible...

Thank you in advance for your suggestions. The request:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 

    // Parent request. Starting point is the exact zipcode matching the search
    ( 
    SELECT distinct User.civilite, User.nom, User.prenom, User.adresse, User.ville as Ville, User.email_confirm, User.cni_verifie, User.diplome_verifie, User.permis_verifie, Besoin.id AS B_id, Besoin.do_accomp, Besoin.req_accomp, Besoin.infos, Besoin.reference, Annonce.type_transport, Annonce.created, null as globalPerimetre , Annonce.cp_depart as CP, Annonce.depart_dom, Annonce.arrivee_dom, LieuDepart.ville as ville_depart, LieuDepart.title as title_depart, LieuArrivee.ville as ville_arrivee, LieuArrivee.title as title_arrivee, 0 as garde, 0 as devoirs FROM km_besoins Besoin 
    INNER JOIN km_users User ON User.id = Besoin.user_id 
    INNER JOIN km_annoncesparents Annonce ON Annonce.besoin_id = Besoin.id 
    left JOIN km_lieux LieuDepart on LieuDepart.id = Annonce.lieu_depart_id 
    left join km_lieux LieuArrivee on LieuArrivee.id = Annonce.lieu_arrivee_id 
    where Besoin.etat="publie" and User.valide=1 and Besoin.valide=1 and (Annonce.date is null or Annonce.date >= '2014-11-24') and (Besoin.req_accomp = 1 or Besoin.do_accomp = 1) and Annonce.cp_depart ='75000' 
    GROUP BY B_id 
    )


UNION

    // Parent request. Arrival point is the exact zipcode matching the search
    ( 
    SELECT distinct User.civilite, User.nom, User.prenom, User.adresse, User.ville as Ville, User.email_confirm, User.cni_verifie, User.diplome_verifie, User.permis_verifie, Besoin.id AS B_id, Besoin.do_accomp, Besoin.req_accomp, Besoin.infos, Besoin.reference, Annonce.type_transport, Annonce.created, null as globalPerimetre , Annonce.cp_arrivee as CP, Annonce.depart_dom, Annonce.arrivee_dom, LieuDepart.ville as ville_depart, LieuDepart.title as title_depart, LieuArrivee.ville as ville_arrivee, LieuArrivee.title as title_arrivee, 0 as garde, 0 as devoirs FROM km_besoins Besoin 
    INNER JOIN km_users User ON User.id = Besoin.user_id 
    INNER JOIN km_annoncesparents Annonce ON Annonce.besoin_id = Besoin.id 
    left join km_lieux LieuDepart on LieuDepart.id = Annonce.lieu_depart_id 
    left JOIN km_lieux LieuArrivee on LieuArrivee.id = Annonce.lieu_arrivee_id 
    where Besoin.etat="publie" and User.valide=1 and Besoin.valide=1 and (Annonce.date is null or Annonce.date >= '2014-11-24') and (Besoin.req_accomp = 1 or Besoin.do_accomp = 1) and Annonce.cp_arrivee ='75000' 
    GROUP BY B_id 
    ) 

UNION

    // Service (somebody takes children to school) request with exact city zipcode
    ( 
    SELECT distinct User.civilite, User.nom, User.prenom, User.adresse, User.ville as Ville, User.email_confirm, User.cni_verifie, User.diplome_verifie, User.permis_verifie, Besoin.id AS B_id, Besoin.do_accomp, Besoin.req_accomp, Besoin.infos, Besoin.reference, Annonce.type_trajet, Annonce.created, Annonce.perimetre as globalPerimetre, Perimetre.code_postal as CP, null, null, null, null, null, null, Annonce.garde, Annonce.devoirs FROM km_besoins Besoin INNER JOIN km_users User ON User.id = Besoin.user_id 
    INNER JOIN km_annoncesaccompas Annonce ON Annonce.besoin_id = Besoin.id 
    INNER JOIN km_perimetres Perimetre ON Perimetre.annoncesaccompa_id = Annonce.id AND Perimetre.code_postal ='75000' 
    inner join km_accompahoraires Service on Service.annoncesaccompa_id = Annonce.id 
    where Besoin.etat="publie" and User.valide=1 and Besoin.valide=1 and (Besoin.req_accomp = 0 and Besoin.do_accomp = 1) 
    GROUP BY B_id 
    )

UNION 

    // Parent request. Starting point is in an area close to the searched zipcode
    ( 
    SELECT distinct User.civilite, User.nom, User.prenom, User.adresse, User.ville as Ville, User.email_confirm, User.cni_verifie, User.diplome_verifie, User.permis_verifie, Besoin.id AS B_id, Besoin.do_accomp, Besoin.req_accomp, Besoin.infos, Besoin.reference, Annonce.type_transport, Annonce.created, null as globalPerimetre , Annonce.cp_depart as CP, Annonce.depart_dom, Annonce.arrivee_dom, LieuDepart.ville as ville_depart, LieuDepart.title as title_depart, LieuArrivee.ville as ville_arrivee, LieuArrivee.title as title_arrivee, 0 as garde, 0 as devoirs FROM km_besoins Besoin 
    INNER JOIN km_users User ON User.id = Besoin.user_id 
    INNER JOIN km_annoncesparents Annonce ON Annonce.besoin_id = Besoin.id 
    left JOIN km_lieux LieuDepart on LieuDepart.id = Annonce.lieu_depart_id 
    left join km_lieux LieuArrivee on LieuArrivee.id = Annonce.lieu_arrivee_id 
    where Besoin.etat="publie" and User.valide=1 and Besoin.valide=1 and (Annonce.date is null or Annonce.date >= '2014-11-24') and (Besoin.req_accomp = 1 or Besoin.do_accomp = 1) and Annonce.cp_depart in (75001,75002,75003,75004,75005,75006,75007,75008,75009,75010,75011,75012,75013,75014,75015,75016,75017,75018,75019,75020,75116,93400,93310,94250,92170,92240,94270,94200,92110,93170,92120,94800,94160,93230,93500,92200,93100,94110,92300,93260,93120,93300,9430075001,75002,75003,75004,75005,75006,75007,75008,75009,75010,75011,75012,75013,75014,75015,75016,75017,75018,75019,75020,75116,93400,93310,94250,92170,92240,94270,94200,92110,93170,92120,94800,94160,93230,93500,92200,93100,94110,92300,93260,93120,93300,94300)
    GROUP BY B_id 
    ) 

UNION

    // Parent request. Arrival point is in an area close to the searched zipcode
    ( 
    SELECT distinct User.civilite, User.nom, User.prenom, User.adresse, User.ville as Ville, User.email_confirm, User.cni_verifie, User.diplome_verifie, User.permis_verifie, Besoin.id AS B_id, Besoin.do_accomp, Besoin.req_accomp, Besoin.infos, Besoin.reference, Annonce.type_transport, Annonce.created, null as globalPerimetre , Annonce.cp_arrivee as CP, Annonce.depart_dom, Annonce.arrivee_dom, LieuDepart.ville as ville_depart, LieuDepart.title as title_depart, LieuArrivee.ville as ville_arrivee, LieuArrivee.title as title_arrivee, 0 as garde, 0 as devoirs FROM km_besoins Besoin 
    INNER JOIN km_users User ON User.id = Besoin.user_id 
    INNER JOIN km_annoncesparents Annonce ON Annonce.besoin_id = Besoin.id 
    left join km_lieux LieuDepart on LieuDepart.id = Annonce.lieu_depart_id 
    left JOIN km_lieux LieuArrivee on LieuArrivee.id = Annonce.lieu_arrivee_id 
    where Besoin.etat="publie" and User.valide=1 and Besoin.valide=1 and (Annonce.date is null or Annonce.date >= '2014-11-24') and (Besoin.req_accomp = 1 or Besoin.do_accomp = 1) and Annonce.cp_arrivee in (75001,75002,75003,75004,75005,75006,75007,75008,75009,75010,75011,75012,75013,75014,75015,75016,75017,75018,75019,75020,75116,93400,93310,94250,92170,92240,94270,94200,92110,93170,92120,94800,94160,93230,93500,92200,93100,94110,92300,93260,93120,93300,9430075001,75002,75003,75004,75005,75006,75007,75008,75009,75010,75011,75012,75013,75014,75015,75016,75017,75018,75019,75020,75116,93400,93310,94250,92170,92240,94270,94200,92110,93170,92120,94800,94160,93230,93500,92200,93100,94110,92300,93260,93120,93300,94300) 
    GROUP BY B_id 
    ) 

UNION

    // Service request with city zipcode in an area close to the searched zipcode
    (
    SELECT distinct User.civilite, User.nom, User.prenom, User.adresse, User.ville as Ville, User.email_confirm, User.cni_verifie, User.diplome_verifie, User.permis_verifie, Besoin.id AS B_id, Besoin.do_accomp, Besoin.req_accomp, Besoin.infos, Besoin.reference, Annonce.type_trajet, Annonce.created, Annonce.perimetre as globalPerimetre, Perimetre.code_postal as CP, null, null, null, null, null, null, Annonce.garde, Annonce.devoirs FROM km_besoins Besoin 
    INNER JOIN km_users User ON User.id = Besoin.user_id INNER JOIN km_annoncesaccompas Annonce ON Annonce.besoin_id = Besoin.id 
    INNER JOIN km_perimetres Perimetre ON Perimetre.annoncesaccompa_id = Annonce.id AND Perimetre.code_postal in (75001,75002,75003,75004,75005,75006,75007,75008,75009,75010,75011,75012,75013,75014,75015,75016,75017,75018,75019,75020,75116,93400,93310,94250,92170,92240,94270,94200,92110,93170,92120,94800,94160,93230,93500,92200,93100,94110,92300,93260,93120,93300,9430075001,75002,75003,75004,75005,75006,75007,75008,75009,75010,75011,75012,75013,75014,75015,75016,75017,75018,75019,75020,75116,93400,93310,94250,92170,92240,94270,94200,92110,93170,92120,94800,94160,93230,93500,92200,93100,94110,92300,93260,93120,93300,94300) 
    inner join km_accompahoraires Service on Service.annoncesaccompa_id = Annonce.id where Besoin.etat="publie" and User.valide=1 and Besoin.valide=1 and (Besoin.req_accomp = 0 and Besoin.do_accomp = 1) 
    GROUP BY B_id 

    ) 


) 
as T1 

group by T1.B_id ORDER BY field(T1.CP, 75000,75001,75002,75003,75004,75005,75006,75007,75008,75009,75010,75011,75012,75013,75014,75015,75016,75017,75018,75019,75020,75116,93400,93310,94250,92170,92240,94270,94200,92110,93170,92120,94800,94160,93230,93500,92200,93100,94110,92300,93260,93120,93300,9430075001,75002,75003,75004,75005,75006,75007,75008,75009,75010,75011,75012,75013,75014,75015,75016,75017,75018,75019,75020,75116,93400,93310,94250,92170,92240,94270,94200,92110,93170,92120,94800,94160,93230,93500,92200,93100,94110,92300,93260,93120,93300,94300), 
T1.B_id desc
```

Comment: I answer to my own post : I rewrote the query a little bit and it runs correctly now, except for some more detailed searchs as Service (which searches on hours ranges ).
For those cases, it seems that the mysql server included in our hosting solution is undersized.
Anyway, thanx to those people who took some times to read.